# How to render the same input element in more cells in ObservableHQ

Tags: javascript, observablehq

Let's say I have the following checkbox element in Observablehq:

```
viewof myFilter = checkbox({
  title: "Foo",
  description: "bar",
  options: myOptions,
  })
```

I want to render the same element in more distinct cells along a notebook and I want to synchronize all their selections. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you’re using Jeremy Ashkenas’s [venerable inputs library](https://observablehq.com/@jashkenas/inputs). There’s a newer [official Inputs library](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/inputs), which is already included on the page (you don’t have to import it).

The official inputs support synchronization using `Inputs.bind` ([more info](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/synchronized-inputs)). For example, these two cells produce two sets of synchronized checkboxes:

```js
viewof a = Inputs.checkbox(["Foo", "bar"])
```

```js
Inputs.bind(Inputs.checkbox(["Foo", "bar"]), viewof a)
```

[Here’s a demo](https://observablehq.com/d/166f4612a1bf1da9).

The official inputs checkbox API is roughly like `Inputs.checkbox(arrayOfChoices, optionsObject)`. Instead of title and description, there’s just a label: `Inputs.checkbox(["Foo", "bar"], {label: "Your choice"})`. [More documentation.](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/input-checkbox)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I ended up using the official input library. Thanx!